# Program blowing up after using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Modifying my reverse a string function to add recursion.  Unfortunately, my program keeps blowing up.

Stepped through my code in Visual Studio and for some reason the watch window will say i is equal to the length of the string (i.e. the terminating condition to exit the while loop).  I step over it one last time and it says i is now one less than the string length.  Then it stays in the while loop forever.

I know this sounds confusing, so I will give an example. I enter "Spongebob" and it does everything I want it to (i.e. says the length of Spongebob is 9, prints "bobegnopS", increments i to the string length, etc), but then it says i is now 8 (i.e. it was just at 9) and never exits the while loop.

Here is my ReverseString() function:

```
void ReverseString(char * string, bool stringReversed, int stringLength, int i)
{
    i++;
    if(!stringReversed)
    {
        while(*string != '\0')
        string++;
    }
    stringReversed = true;

    while(i < stringLength)
    {
        string--;
        std::cout << *string;
        ReverseString(string, stringReversed, stringLength, i);
    }
   }
```

Here is the call:

```
    case 3:
    //Learn By Doing 16.6
    {
        char string[BUFFER_LENGTH];
        bool stringReversed = false;

        int base = 0;
        int exponent = 0;

        std::cout << "\nEnter base: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> base;

        std::cout << "\nEnter exponent: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> exponent;

        //Print pow
        NewLine();
        std::cout << base << " to the " << exponent << " is " << pow(base, exponent);

        //Reverse string using recursion
        std::cout << "\nEnter string: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> string;


        NewLine();
        int stringLength = strlen(string);
        int i = 0;
        ReverseString(string, stringReversed, stringLength, i);

    }
```

Comment: You need a return point in ReverseString function

Comment: You mean I cannot have ReverseString be void since it is a recursive function??  So I should make it char * ReverseString making it return a character pointer??

Comment: I don't mean return type, void function can still return;

Answer (score 3):

When you write a recursive function you always need to specify condition when to stop. Imagine you want to write naive factorial recursive implementation. So idea is to calculate it like this:

```
n! = n * (n-1) *...*2*1
```

If you look into sequence you can see that you need to stop at value 1. So naive recursive implementation could be this:

```
int factorial( int n )
{
   // stop when we reached 1
   // otherwise we never finish
   if( n == 1 ) return 1; 
   // now do the magic
   return n * factorial( n - 1 );
}
```

The fact that you need to return a value or not does not change the fact that you need to put a stop condition, otherwise your recursive function will never stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ReverseString(char * string, bool stringReversed, int stringLength, int i)
{
  ...
  while(i < stringLength)
  {
    string--;
    std::cout << *string;
    ReverseString(string, stringReversed, stringLength, i);
  }
}
```

Nothing inside the loop modifies `i` or `stringLength` (the function `ReverseString` takes them by value, not by reference.) So it can never terminate.